# How mock then and catch in jest with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to run a jest spyOn on a mongoose method that contains a promise.

but it is returning me an error: Received message: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'then')"

I have a repository with this function:

```
async getByEndpointId(endpointId: string) {
 return await this._requestModel.find({endpointId})
  .then((request) => request.filter((req) => !req.deleted))
  .catch((error) -> console.log("One Error"))
}
```

When I try to test with jest this way:

```
jest.spyOn(mockEndpointModel, 'find').mockReturnValue(value as any)
```

The runntime show me this error:

Received message: "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'then')"

if I remove the then and catch methods my test works

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mocking a promise rather than having Jest mock a resolve or reject which *is* a promise? `jest.spyOn(mockEndpointModel, 'find').mockResolvedValue(value)` or `jest.spyOn(mockEndpointModel, 'find').mockRejectedValue(new Error('Something bad happened')`

[This repo has a bunch of Nest unit testing samples and might be useful to you](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs)

Comment: I found in your repo one way to make this and works:

```
jest.spyOn(mockEndpointModel, 'find').mockReturnValue({
      exec: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(value),
} as any);
```

Comment: This is specific to mongoose and the way the `exec` call works. Notice how the service code is all `find(options).exec()` that's why the `find` and `exec` methods are both mocked. Based on your code, you should just have your `find` mock resolve a promise.

Comment: At first it didn't work but now I managed to make it work, thanks

`jest.spyOn(mockEndpointModel, 'find').mockResolvedValue(value)`